# Proof there isn't a vector u such Su=u where S is the rotation transformation in R2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, rotations

We have the rotation matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{pmatrix}

**Proof**: there isn't exist a vector $u \in\ {\mathbb{R}^2}$ ($u\neq0$) such $Au=u$ where $A$ is the rotation matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: So, looks like you're giving homework to all users of this site.

Comment: How to write matrices: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/how-to-input-matrices-when-posting-questions-at-math-stackexchange

Comment: What if $\theta$ is zero, or more generally, an integer multiple of $2\pi$?  Note that $Au = u$ is equivalent to $(A-I)u = 0$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix (of the same size as $A$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

First note that if $\theta=2k\pi$ the matrix is the identity matrix, so the statement in OP can be true only for $\theta\ne 2k\pi$.

Now note that $Ru=u$ means that the matrix $R$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, so find the eigenvalues of your matrix and show that they are different from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrix is turning your vector. It is just a rotation. If you will rotate vector about axis, you can get your initial vector iff $\theta=2\pi k$ or your vector equals to zero.

Comment: Sorry for my English